# || operator in c++ for vector norm

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword, norm

I'm trying to write a own "library" for vectors where I can define **operators** such as **"*"** for scalar multiplication and **"+"** for vector addition etc. I think I got most of it right, but now I'm trying to define a operator for the l2 norm of a vector using **"| |"**, meaning this:

```
Vector v;
// let v be (3, 4)
double a = |v|;
// then a should be 5 (sqrt(16 + 9))
```

but then I get this error:

```
main.cpp:11:17: error: no match for 'operator|' (operand types are 'Vector' and 'int')
     double a = v|2|;
               ~^~
main.cpp:11:20: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
     double a = v|2|;
```

Now here I'm struggling to define the operator ||...

I tried doing something like this:

```
double Vector::operator||(int){
//  here I used the scalar product to calculate the norm
    double d = (*this) * (*this);
    return sqrt(d);
}
```

or I tried defining it as friend function with two parameters. I think the main problem is what parameters I have to give the operator because it always requiers two (or one if its a member function). I just cant figure out a way to do it...

Has anyone of you an idea how solve this or is there no solution for this and I have to use a normal function?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: operators in c++ have a required syntax. You can't make up your own operator.

Comment: You can't make up your own operators or change the syntax of existing operators.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers!

Comment: Both operators `|` and `||` are binary - they are used in expressions with exactly two arguments (no more, no less) such as `a | b` or `a || b` respectively.   It is not possible to implement other forms of either operator that differ from what the language already supports since that is specifically forbidden by the C++ standard.  In other words, you can't add a new meaning for either `|` or `||`  (or any other operator) that allows `|a|` to even be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, because C++ doesn't support such a syntax. The best you can do is to create a function called something like `magnitude` and do your calculations in it. Like this:

```
template <typename T>
T magnitude(std::vector<T> const& vec) { ... }

double a = magnitude(v);
```

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of how much you abuse C++'s syntax, I'm afraid there's no way to turn `double a = |v|;` into valid code, because `|` can only be a binary infix operator.

Comment: Couldn't resist the temptation... [`int a = _| v |_;`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/FL9Nyy) I feel sorry for this abuse

Comment: @Ayxan that *is* terrible :p